# Batch: How to run a program when the computer is idle and stop when it's used?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to run a Windows batch (or any other command line software would do fine) that would run a program when the computer has been idle for a minute and stop it when it's used. I should obviously start it back again when it's idle again.

Any ideas? Couldn't find anything that doesn't use GUI.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Win-7 you can do that in task scheduler. Open the task scheduler, select My Task Schedules, and choose Create Task (not create basic task). Give it a name, click the Actions tab and choose the program you want to run. Choose the Conditions tab, click on "run if idle for xxx minutes", and check stop running if computer ceases to be idle.

Comment: Thanks, but that would't work, I need to deploy this in several computers and some don't have admin right.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to need to get admin rights regardless of how you try to accomplish this. It's possible to deploy a task scheduler configuration to multiple computers, also.